# One of delivery charge for paypal shopping cart

Tags: paypal, shopping-cart

Is there a way of setting a one of delivery charge for multiple items using the paypal shopping cart. I have a website that sells postcards for the small local museum but I can only get the delivery charge added on for every different item, or not at all. Delivery is 65p, So if someone buys;
6 x "a" postcard
there is one delivery charge 65p.
The problem is that when someone orders;
1 x "a" postcard
1 x "b" postcard
1 x "c" postcard
1 x "d" postcard
1 x "e" postcard
1 x "f" postcard
The delivery charge is £3.90 which is way too much for 6 postcards. 
Is there a way of setting the delivery charge to 65p for any number of variations?
Thanks anyone who can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, Worked it out! I think I am just going to have to base the shipping on a total order value and not specify it at all in my coding... Heres what I did in case anyone else finds this with the same problem.

Login to Paypal account.
Click on the "Profile" tab near the top of the page and under "Selling Preferences" click on the "Shipping Calculations" link and follow the steps to set up for instance £0.01 - £9.99 delivery £1.15, £10.00-£14.99 delivery £1.95 etc etc etc.

Thanks for your help everyone!!

Answer (score 2):

I think PayPal has a value called "shipping_1" and "shipping_2", depending on the platforn you just need to override these values, we used something like this for our PHP form

```
<input type="hidden" name="shipping_1" value="<?php echo $order->delivery - $order->discount_delivery ?>">
```

Answer (score 2):

[This link](https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/ebook/PP_WebsitePaymentsStandard_IntegrationGuide/shopping_cart.html) says you can do this by setting

**Setting the Shipping Charge for the Entire Cart**

> Use the shipping variable without
>   additional shipping2 variables to
>   specify the shipping charge for the
>   entire transaction. The value of
>   shipping is used for the shipping
>   charges, regardless of the merchant’s
>   profile-based shipping rates and rate
>   basis.

Also see https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?&cmd=_render-content&content_ID=brc/three_common_shipping_issues